# Create a string from pieces of another string?

Tags: python, string, python-2.7

I need to create a string from pieces of another string. 
For example, I need to create this:

```
"*ND.v80_8.0.5 *"
```

(the asterisks need to be there)

I have this variable:

```
versionInstall
```

which is basically `"8.0.0.5"`.

I have written this:

```
searchOff = ('*ND.v' + versionInstall.split(".")[0] + versionInstall.split(".")[1]
               + '_' + versionInstall.split(".")[0] + '.' + versionInstall.split(".")[1]
               + '.' + fixpack + '*')
```

Sincerely, it works but I don't like it and I would like to know if there is any other way to form the variable?

Comment: Well right off the bat, you should just save the result of `versionInstall.split(".")` and reuse that result, rather than calling `split` several times redundantly.

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest thing in my opinion in this type of situation is to use [string formatting](https://pyformat.info/#simple):

```
In [1]: versionInstall = '8.0.0.5'

In [2]: version_info = versionInstall.split('.')

In [3]: version_info
Out[3]: ['8', '0', '0', '5']

In [4]: fixpack = '5'

In [5]: searchOff = '*ND.v{v0}{v1}_{v0}.{v1}.{fixpack}*'.format(v0=version_info[0], v1=version_info[1], fixpack=fixpack)

In [6]: searchOff
Out[6]: '*ND.v80_8.0.5*'
```

Also, unless you have to, I would avoid using camel case and use [snake case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snake_case) instead (e.g., `searchOff` -> `search_off`), as this is the convention in the community.